# Highcharts Packed Bubble Not Scaling Properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a working version of my issue here:

https://jsfiddle.net/upcheezy/45ps3j9t/4/

```
{
        "name": "Normal",
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Additional Info",
                "value": 286
            },
            {
                "name": "Add Service Area",
                "value": 117
            },
            {
                "name": "Cancel",
                "value": 13168
            },
            {
                "name": "Multiple",
                "value": 600
            },
            {
                "name": "New",
                "value": 721391
            },
            {
                "name": "No Show",
                "value": 32872
            },
            {
                "name": "Remark",
                "value": 38699
            },
            {
                "name": "Resend",
                "value": 14160
            },
            {
                "name": "Update",
                "value": 224260
            }
        ]
    }
```

This chart doesn't check out visually because the scale of the bubbles does not accurately reflect the data. For example, it seems like all of the "Normal" category data values are the exact same size, when within the data array, the values are not even close! Can someone please tell me if this is normal behavior with HighCharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected behavior for adjusting size of the bubbles, use [maxSize](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.packedbubble.maxSize),
[minSize](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.packedbubble.minSize) to adjusting.

> Packed Bubble charts with a dataset of either many small or large
> values need some tweaking of the options to control the size of the
> bubbles displayed. The minimum and maximum size of bubbles is
> configured by two parameters: minSize and maxSize Bubbles will
> automatically size between the minSize and maxSize to reflect the
> volume of each bubble. Can be either pixels (when no unit is given),
> or a percentage of the smallest one of the plot width and height.

Article: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/packed-bubble#bubble-sizes

Comment: Also we can try different `sizeBy` values to see what properties are best to scale the graph as we desire.